# Merging SQL Result rows together

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I am working on an EAV storage system for storing schemaless meta data about an object, and am now working on a way to have it searchable, but have most of the processing done by the Database Server.

The table of the EAV is:

```
`entityID` - INT(11)
`entity` - VARCHAR(128)
`attribute` - VARCHAR(128)
`value` - BLOB
```

This is my statement:

```
SELECT 
    `entity`,
    (CASE WHEN `attribute` = 'bob' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) `bob`,
    (CASE WHEN `attribute` = 'dean' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) `dean`
FROM `eav`
```

which returns a nice set of rows (as expected) like this:

```
+----------+------+------+
|  entity  | bob  | dean |
+----------+------+------+
| testEnt  | foo  | NULL | // attribute = bob
+----------+------+------+
| testEnt  | NULL | NULL | // another test attribute
+----------+------+------+
| testEnt  | NULL | NULL | // another test attribute
+----------+------+------+
| testEnt2 | foo  | NULL | // attribute = bob
+----------+------+------+
| testEnt2 | NULL | foo  | // attribute = dean
+----------+------+------+
```

but when I attach `GROUP BY (Entity)`, the result turns into this:

```
+----------+------+------+
|  entity  | bob  | dean |
+----------+------+------+
| testEnt  | foo  | NULL |
+----------+------+------+
| testEnt2 | foo  | NULL |
+----------+------+------+
```

so using the `HAVING` syntax after that stops working. Is there a way so that the result returned is:

```
+----------+------+------+
|  entity  | bob  | dean |
+----------+------+------+
| testEnt  | foo  | NULL |
+----------+------+------+
| testEnt2 | foo  | foo  |
+----------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply an aggregate function with the `CASE` and the `GROUP BY`. Since the values are strings you can use either a `MAX()` or `MIN()` to return the result:

```
SELECT 
    `entity`,
    Max(CASE WHEN `attribute` = 'bob' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) `bob`,
    Max(CASE WHEN `attribute` = 'dean' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) `dean`
FROM `eav`
group by `entity`
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69195/1)

In the event, you have an unknown number of `attribute` values to return, you can use a prepared statement to get the result:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when attribute = ''',
      attribute,
      ''' then value end) AS ',
      attribute
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM eav;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT entity, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM eav 
                   GROUP BY entity');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69195/3)

The result for both will be:

```
|   ENTITY | BOB |   DEAN |
---------------------------
|  testEnt | foo | (null) |
| testEnt2 | foo |    foo |
```

Answer (score 3):

The only problem with is that you did `GROUP` your record but you haven't aggregate the fields. Try it by aggregating the field using `MAX`.

```
SELECT 
    `entity`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `attribute` = 'bob' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) `bob`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `attribute` = 'dean' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) `dean`
FROM `eav`
GROUP BY `entity`
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a6c3/1)